# How can I use assets placed in the views directory in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a **[online newspaper/blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/twigPress/)** with **CodeIgniter 3.1.8** and Bootstrap 4. I have decided to add themes to it. The application is **not HMVC**, only MVC.

I thought it was a good idea to use the *Twig* template engine to the theme(s). For this purpose, I use **[CodeIgniter Simple and Secure Twig](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig)**.

I want the *views and assets* corresponding to each theme to be placed *in the same directory*, with the theme's name.

I am trying to load the theme's assets from the views directory, like, for instance: `application/views/themes/mytheme/assets/css/main.css`.

In the post controller I have added the line `$this->twig->addGlobal('maincss', base_url('application/views/themes/mytheme/assets/css/main.css'))`;

```
public function index() {

    //call initialization method
    $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

    //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);

    $this->twig->addGlobal('siteTitle', 'My Awesome Site');
    //CSS, JS and other resources add to twig here, because PHP and Codeigniter functions are not available from Twig templates
    $this->twig->addGlobal('maincss', base_url('application/views/themes/mytheme/assets/css/main.css'));

    $this->twig->display('themes/mytheme/layout', $data);
}
```

In layout.twig I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{maincss}}">
```

Instead of the desired result, I get a **403 Forbidden** page. To fix this issue, I added `application/views/themes` to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|application/views/themes/|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

The above solution fails for a reason I can not figure out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could have the "assets" inside the application folders but you would have to include the CSS directly into the file and not have the browser fetch it (as there is no direct access allowed using href) . So CI and/or Twig would let you do that. But you could consider it better to use a <link...> as you have done and let the browser cache those files "possibly" reducing the page load times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder and name it assets outside application and then link it by using base_url like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/back/css/bootstrap.min.css"')?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Following **khawaja umar's** advice I split my theme into views and assets: I have the theme's assets (css, images, scripts) inside `myapp/themes/mytheme/assets` and the theme's views in `myapp/application/views/themes/mytheme`.

Tn the controller I have these 2 lines to deal with each of the team's parts (assets and views):

```
$this->twig->addGlobal('maincss', base_url('themes/mytheme/assets/css/main.css'));
$this->twig->display('themes/mytheme/layout', $data);
```

In the `layout.twig` file I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{maincss}}">
```

I have reached the conclusion that this is the best approach,  including from a *security* standpoint.